# Agile Web Development Rails 5 test failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I just finished creating the Depot app from the Agile Web Development with Rails 5 textbook. For some reason, I am getting errors & failures when I run 'rails test'. Can someone explain why this is happening?

My Github repository is here: https://github.com/christopheragnus/Agile_Web_Development_with_Rails_5

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-3:depot Agnus$ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 45997
Run options: --seed 52040

# Running:

..............F

Failure:
LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_create_line_item [/Users/Agnus/Dropbox/CA/AgileWebDevelopment/depot/test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:25]:
<Your Cart> expected but was
<>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


bin/rails test test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:18

..E

Error:
OrderMailerTest#test_shipped:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `login_url' for #<OrderMailerTest:0x007ff7b60cc410>
Did you mean?  login_as
    test/test_helper.rb:12:in `login_as'
    test/test_helper.rb:20:in `setup'


bin/rails test test/mailers/order_mailer_test.rb:12

E

Error:
OrderMailerTest#test_received:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `login_url' for #<OrderMailerTest:0x007ff7b6058880>
Did you mean?  login_as
    test/test_helper.rb:12:in `login_as'
    test/test_helper.rb:20:in `setup'


bin/rails test test/mailers/order_mailer_test.rb:4

E

Error:
AdminControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `admin_index_url' for #<AdminControllerTest:0x007ff7b4ca8880>
    test/controllers/admin_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:AdminControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/admin_controller_test.rb:4

...........................

Finished in 5.740751s, 8.1871 runs/s, 14.4580 assertions/s.
47 runs, 83 assertions, 1 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: The message is pretty self explanatory ...

Comment: @rak007 he's literally taking a course to build your first ruby app

Answer (score 0):

The undefined errors mean just that: you are calling "login_url" but rails cannot find it anywhere. If you simply copy pasted code from the book you should go to the section where they create this helper file and see where they defined the login_url.

The test failure, opposed to the error, is that it is expecting an h2 element to exist with the name "Your Cart" but it cannot find it. To debug this, you could either go through the code and make sure all the routing/rerouting is correct and that the views are correctly structured and there's no typos- or run the app and go through what the test is doing and see if the results you are seeing is what is expected. Then- we can go from there.

As a rule of thumb, it is good to get into the habit of googling errors which can help give you an idea of where to troubleshoot the issues in your project.